# Wmi Security on Windows 8

Tags: security, windows-8, wmi, remote-access

I have some problems regarding WMI scripting on Windows 8. More precisely, remote connection from Win7(not that relevant) to Windows 8. Note that the following issues do not happen when the client machine runs Windows 7.

First one is getting data regarding the current shares on that machine. Specifically, I am trying to get the Path property of the shares, that is local path.

In windows 7 it works perfectly, in windows 8 however it returns null(ran with wbemtest from remote computer).

First I thought that there is a problem with the WMI system. Then I ran the same query directly on the win8 machine. That returned the actual local path of the share. This led me to believe that there are problems with the WMI security on that machine.

Another issue I have with WMI on win8 is that it does not allow me to run things as Administrator, even though the user used to log is is the Administrator.

Regarding the security settings on the win8 machine, I gradually lowered them to try the exact position in which I can operate. I have reached the level where Everyone has every access, so it is the lowest security possible. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of just playing with security around Wmimgmt.msc and dcomcnfg I finally found a way to run wmi as administrator on a remote machine. Although this is not exactly what I did, I found that this works great: I activated the Administrator account: net user administrator /active:yes. Then I entered User accounts and set a password for the Administrator account. I then opened Wmimgmt.msc and set allow on all security for the Root node and cimv2 node. After this Wmi remotely(logged on as administrator) works as a charm